# How to return all rows containing a certain value using excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need an excel formula that will select all rows containing a certain keyword, and then either return a pivot table of these rows, or copy them to another sheet in the workbook.  I cannot use VBA or a filter, it has to be done with excel functions.  It would also be helpful if it could search across multiple sheets.

This is what I have so far

```
=INDEX($A$2:$B$29,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$29=$G$2,ROW($B$2:$B$29)),ROW(1:1))-1,1)
```

But it only returns a single value from the rows that match, not entire rows, and not as a pivot table.

Comment: please make your first move ahead and how far you got through

Comment: I've been using this     =INDEX($A$2:$B$29,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$29=$G$2,ROW($B$2:$B$29)),ROW(1:1))-1,1)    but it only returns a single value, what I need is it to return the entire rows.

Comment: ok just wait i'm switching on windows

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution for this regarding two possibilities:

Given your data are stowed through Column A of Sheet 1.

- The values seached amongst are not reduplicated, that means no two identical occurences can be found:

You should therefor create a new sheet then copy the value 0 inside the case A1, then copy this line through other rows of same column.

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("Sheet1!$A"&MATCH("*a*";INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(IF(ISNUMBER(A1);A1;MATCH(A1;Sheet1!$A$1:A100;0))+1;1;1;1)):Sheet1!A100;0)+IF(ISNUMBER(A1);A1;MATCH(A1;Sheet1!$A$1:Sheet1!A100;0)));"")
```

- The values searched between contains duplicates:

Copy this through `A2 -> A100` and 0 in `A1`

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("*a*";INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(A1+1;1)):Sheet1!A100;0)+A1;"")
```

then copy this throughout `B2 -> B100`

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(A2;1));"")
```

Automatically `A1` and `A2` should increment respectively of actual row, Also there is a way to cram (or concatenate) all results inside one whole cell because my version of EXCEL doesnt include returning pivot tables.